# jQuery - slide down instead of slide up

Tags: jquery, html, css, scrollbar, slide

How to make the same as [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AwcUX/1/), but the difference is the green box should slide down to disappear (and slide up to appear when you click the `click here` link in the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/AwcUX/1/) one more time).

The two strings

```
/*position:absolute;*/
/*bottom:0px;*/
```

which are commented in the css part of [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AwcUX/1/) doesn't work well if uncomment because it really starts to slide down, but the browser scroll bar disappers - not good.

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is: please double check your example, you can't see the bottom of the green block.

Comment: Sorry didn't noticed that, but now updated my answer with working demo link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Edited:

Add a `<div>` with an `id` **sliderWrapper** and give it `100%` **width** as given below.

```
<div width="100%" id="sliderWrapper">        
    <div id="slider" style="border:1px solid red;">
        <h1>1</h1><h1>2</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>4</h1><h1>F</h1>

        <h1>1</h1><h1>2</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>4</h1><h1>E</h1>

        <h1>1</h1><h1>2</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>4</h1><h1>D</h1>

        <h1>1</h1><h1>2</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>4</h1><h1>C</h1>

        <h1>1</h1><h1>2</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>4</h1><h1>B</h1>

        <h1>A</h1><h1>A</h1><h1>A</h1><h1>A</h1><h1>A</h1>

         <h1>6</h1><h1>7</h1><h1>8</h1><h1>9</h1><h1>10</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Keep following css rules for `#slider`**

```
  #slider {
      background : green;             
      width:100px;
      margin:20px auto 0 auto;
   }
```

**Replace following line with `$('#slider').slideToggle(500)`**

```
 if(hid) { $('#sliderWrapper').show("slide", { direction:"down" }, 500);} 
 else { $('#sliderWrapper').hide("slide", { direction:"down" }, 500); }
```

[**SEE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/DV3qx/)

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is: please double check your example, you can't see the bottom of the green block.

Comment: @Haradzieniec: Sorry didn't noticed that, but now updated my answer with working demo link.

Comment: Thank you, but now it jumps to the left, when sliding. Trying to get rid of that jumping, still no luck.

Comment: Yeah noticed in firefox but fine in chrome. Strange behavior.

Comment: @Haradzieniec: Finally got the working solution with some tweaking in markup. See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it works. Later I will ask another question. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Edited your jsFiddle!
Used jquery.slideToggle(); and some Css to get the right slide direction!

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AwcUX/23/)**

Comment: Do you see position:absolute; bottom:0; removes the scroll down I noted in my question? You can't see the end of the page. Also, it breaks the align and the link does not fall.