# jQuery: make the example to slide down smoothly

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, slide

I have an almost working code here:
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DV3qx/1/).

What it does? It slides down and and up the green rectangle. There are several issuies here I want to resolve, but the first one is:
I want it slide down **SMOOTHLY** and **all together**, with no space in between, for time of **1500 milliseconds**. Now it works for 500 millisecond and when you click to slide down, the green rectangle slides down faster (I don't understand why).

Also I don't want to change the structure of my html divs, if possible, only additional divs could be added to rewrite the code.

P.S. The other code of jQuery was used several days ago for this solution, but it didn't slide down well in FF (although perfect in Chrome), so it was replaced by the current jQuery code thanks to A.K ( [jQuery - slide down instead of slide up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11859976/jquery-slide-down-instead-of-slide-up))

Answer (score 0):

It is alright for you ? ( [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DV3qx/4/) )

```
 $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $('#slide-link').click(function(){

            var hid = $('#sliderWrapper').is(':hidden')            
            $(this).animate({ top: (1-hid)*($(window).height()) },1500)

            if(hid) {$('#sliderWrapper').stop().show("slide", { direction:"down" }, 2000);}
            else { $('#sliderWrapper').stop().hide("slide", { direction:"down" }, 2000); }

        })
    });
```

I incremented with 500 over 1500 in `if-else` statement

Comment: The same thing... The green block slides down faster than the block where the link is... Some space appeares when sliding...

Comment: Google Chrome 21.0.1180.75 m, Firefox 14.0.1

Comment: with safari is ok... this code is a little messy, I'm trying to put it working on firefox

Comment: It worked fine:) My fault, it had a different velocity because for the same amount of time (500ms or 1500ms or whatever ms) sliderWrapper and slide-link had a different destination to pass. Probably, you had a bigger display resolution and all text was on the same page. That's why on your screen two blocks had the same velocity, no space in between when slide down.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I untherstand your question, is this what you're looking for?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pluda/DV3qx/3/)

Comment: Unfortunately, no... The green block slides down faster than the block where the link is... Some space appeares when sliding...